# Running Jaunt (web-scraper) on Google App Engine: Java

Tags: java, forms, google-app-engine, jaunt-api

I'm trying to submit a form through App Engine and **[Jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/)**. I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jaunt.UserAgent.a(SourceFile:2337)
    at com.jaunt.UserAgent.send(SourceFile:887)
    at com.jaunt.component.Form.submit(SourceFile:1263)
    at ewohnat.server.parse.MyServlet.doJaunt(MyServlet.java:118)
```

when I try to run this code:

```
UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
userAgent.visit("www.someurl.com");
Form form = userAgent.doc.forms[0];
form.setCheckBox("cb", true);
form.submit();
```

The exception is thrown on the last line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    form.submit();
```

Doesn't work properly.
Use method with argument instead

```
    form.submit(String value);
```